# Elastic Search on multiple fields with fuzziness matches and sort on multiple fields combined scores

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, lumen, fuzzy-search

I'm working with Elastic Search in Laravel my index has 3 fields `text,mood,haloha_id`.
First I want to match `"haloha_id"`(consider haloha_id as post and text as comments on that post) if match then do further matching.
suppose `"haloha_id"` is matched now I want to match a substring in the "text" field then match "mood"(which is integer either 0,1,2 etc) "mood should be matched only if some of "text" is matched otherwise not.I'm making Like Mine query mean comments matching with user's comments for the specific post will be shown only. The issue in my query is that

- My own Comments doesn't appear to the top hence its matched 100%
- If someone "mood" and "comments" matched 100% to mine then it doesn't appear to the top.

  **I removed "mood" related query but score has no effect it means score doesn't include mood matched score.**

**Here is my query.**

```
 "query"=>[      

    "bool"=>[                                
        "should"=>[
            "match"=>[
                "text"=>[
                    "query"=>$userHaloha->filtered_text,
                    "fuzziness"=>"AUTO",                
                ]
            ]                           
        ],
        "minimum_should_match"=>1,
        "must"=>[
            "match"=>[
                "mood"=>$userHaloha->mood,            
            ],
            "match"=>[
                "haloha_id"=>$userHaloha->haloha_id
            ]
        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query is self explanatory. I have added "haloha_id" to filter block (which doesnot score documents), "text" to must block(to score documents) and "mood" to should block(to boost documents)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "haloha_id": "5ecf6bff25a36366cd134db2"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "text": {
              "query": "chilli ",
              "fuzziness": "auto"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "mood": {
              "value": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Issue in mood:3 getting higher ranked than mood:2(searched term in should clause) is due to sharding

From [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/consistent-scoring.html#_relevancy_looks_wrong)

> If you notice that two documents with the same content get different
>   scores or that an exact match is not ranked first, then the issue
>   might be related to sharding. By default, Elasticsearch makes each
>   shard responsible for producing its own scores. However since index
>   statistics are an important contributor to the scores, this only works
>   well if shards have similar index statistics. The assumption is that
>   since documents are routed evenly to shards by default, then index
>   statistics should be very similar and scoring would work as expected.
>   However in the event that you either:
>
> use routing at index time, query multiple indices, or have too little
>   data in your index then there are good chances that all shards that
>   are involved in the search request do not have similar index
>   statistics and relevancy could be bad.
>
> If you have a small dataset, the easiest way to work around this issue
>   is to index everything into an index that has a single shard
>   (index.number_of_shards: 1), which is the default. Then index
>   statistics will be the same for all documents and scores will be
>   consistent.

Comment: Thank you jespreet for your response and effort but still I have some issues, 1- My own comment is on 2nd number it should be on top(1st) 2- Other comments are being shown even substring or mood is not being matched

Comment: @AliBhutta What is the issue?

Comment: Issue 1: my own comment is showing on 2nd numbr instead of 1st number issue 2: irrelevant comments are being shown even if no mood or substring is not matched with them

Comment: @AliBhutta can you provide example and  input text

Comment: yeah sure, in example my text is "chilli" and mood is 2, what I'm getting at first  
"text" => "chilli cosy "
 "mood" => 2 at secod 
"text" => "chilli "
      "mood" => 2 (my own comment) at 7th number "text" => " "
      "mood" => 1

Comment: @AliBhutta I tried with my query , "text" => "chilli " got higher score.  Can you provide full document for  first and second ranked document

Comment: 0 => array:5 [
    "_index" => "halohas"
    "_type" => "haloha"
    "_id" => "5ecf8d7225a36366cc12b8c4"
    "_score" => 7.4376016
    "_source" => array:3 [
      "haloha_id" => "5ecf6bff25a36366cd134db2"
      "text" => "chilli cosy "
      "mood" => 2
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:5 [
    "_index" => "halohas"
    "_type" => "haloha"
    "_id" => "5ecf8f9c25a36366cf5fdb32"
    "_score" => 6.5255055
    "_source" => array:3 [
      "haloha_id" => "5ecf6bff25a36366cd134db2"
      "text" => "chilli "
      "mood" => 2
    ]
  ]

Comment: I'm not able to comment here too long text, can u enable chat or provide email so that i can send you there? actually StackOverflow is not allowing me to post too long comment

Comment: It seems like you're the only person who can solve my problem kindly do a favor. I'm new on ElasticSeach plz help me. Thank you

Comment: @AliBhutta Can yoou join this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214893/62080669

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.
------- not able to reply :'(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214894/discussion-between-jaspreet-chahal-and-ali-bhutta).

Comment: @AliBhutta try on this link continue this discussion in chat.